# All I'm askin' / Is about the interesting preposition placement in the song "Respect"

Tags: prepositions, dialects, songs, african-american-vernacular-english, clefts

The Aretha Franklin song "Respect" has the interesting lyric "All I'm askin' / Is for a little respect" [[link](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Twnsdqfbn5js5s76c2s2pvw2h3m?lyrics=1)] where in everyday English, I would expect "All I'm askin' for / Is a little respect".

I've always assumed that this was done for reasons of meter, but it occurred to me recently that for all I know, there could be a variety of English where this sort of phrasing is normal. Is there?

Comment: Song lyrics are one of (if not THE) most common occurence of grammar being pushed aside in favor of rhythm or rhyme. You cannot scrutnize song lyrics with the same expectation of grammatical correctness like you would an essay or a novel.

Comment: @Flater: Yup, I'm aware. That's why I always assumed what I did. But you also can't assume that all varieties of English have the same grammar; and the grammar of this lyric certainly makes sense in the abstract. I'm just not used to people not P-stranding in this context.